# "Variables may not be used here" during terraform init

Tags: terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using Terraform snowflake plugins. I want to use `${terraform.workspace}` variable in `terraform` scope.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    snowflake = {
      source  = "chanzuckerberg/snowflake"
      version = "0.20.0"
    }
  }
  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "data-pf-terraform-backend-${terraform.workspace}"
    key            = "backend/singlife/landing"
    region         = "ap-southeast-1"
    dynamodb_table = "data-pf-snowflake-terraform-state-lock-${terraform.workspace}"
  }
}
```

But I got this error. Variables are not available in this scope?

```
Error: Variables not allowed

  on provider.tf line 9, in terraform:
   9:     bucket         = "data-pf-terraform-backend-${terraform.workspace}"

Variables may not be used here.


Error: Variables not allowed

  on provider.tf line 12, in terraform:
  12:     dynamodb_table = "data-pf-snowflake-terraform-state-lock-${terraform.workspace}"

Variables may not be used here.
```

Comment: Note from the documentation at https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/config.html: "Only one backend may be specified and the configuration may not contain interpolations. Terraform will validate this." You can partially configure the backend and then interactively supply the missing values if you require.

Comment: You may wish to subscribe to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/13022) and add your voice to the many asking for this feature enhancement. Alternatively, the issue contains several suggested workarounds you could consider.

Answer (score 71):

- Set backend.tf

  ```
  terraform {
    backend "azurerm" {}
  }
  ```
- Create a file backend.conf

  ```
  storage_account_name = "deploymanager"
  container_name       = "terraform"
  key                  = "production.terraform.tfstate"
  ```
- Run:

  ```
  terraform init -backend-config=backend.conf
  ```

Comment: This is the way!

Comment: For some reason, this failed in Powershell with error as `too many command line arguments`. But worked when I used command prompt.

Comment: In Powershell use double dash for the argument: `terraform init --backend-config=backend.conf`

Comment: Just in case it's not obvious, you can then `.gitignore` the `.conf` file if it contains secrets, such as HTTP basic auth, etc.

Comment: Can you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77415476/terraform-variables-not-allowed-variables-may-not-be-used-here

Answer (score 9):

The [terraform backend docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/configuration.html) state:

> A backend block cannot refer to named values (like input variables, locals, or data source attributes).

However, the [s3 backend docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/s3.html#multi-account-aws-architecture) show you how you can partition some s3 storage based on the current *workspace*, so each workspace gets its own independent state file. You just can't specify a distinct bucket for each workspace. You can only specify one bucket for all workspaces, but the s3 backend will add the [workspace prefix to the path](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/s3.html#key):

> When using a non-default workspace, the state path will be /workspace_key_prefix/workspace_name/key (see also the workspace_key_prefix configuration).

And one dynamo table will suffice for all workspaces. So just use:

```
  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "data-pf-terraform-backend"
    key            = "terraform.tfstate"
    region         = "ap-southeast-1"
    dynamodb_table = "data-pf-snowflake-terraform-state-lock"
  }
```

And switch workspaces as appropriate before deployments.

Comment: Can you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77415476/terraform-variables-not-allowed-variables-may-not-be-used-here

Answer (score 4):

But how is Jhonny's answer any different? You still cannot put variables in backend.conf, which was the initial question.

```
Initializing the backend...
╷
│ Error: Variables not allowed
│
│   on backend.conf line 1:
│    1: bucket  = "server-${var.account_id}"
│
│ Variables may not be used here.
```

The only way for now is to use a wrapper script that provides env variables, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77415476/terraform-variables-not-allowed-variables-may-not-be-used-here

Answer (score 1):

For terraform and s3 bucket

```
backend.tf
terraform {
  backend "s3" {}
}
backend-conf.tf
bucket         = ""
key            = "terraform/terraform.tfstate"
region         = "us-east-1"

if using gitlab make backend folder then according to your env make folder ie-dev or prod 
then make dev-backend.conf etc
then in your ci file 
terraform init  -backend-config=./backend/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH-backend.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

You could checkout terragrunt, which is a thin wrapper that provides extra tools for keeping your configurations DRY, working with multiple Terraform modules, and managing remote state.

See here: https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/getting-started/quick-start/#keep-your-backend-configuration-dry

Answer (score -3):

Check Jhonny's solution first:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/69664785/132438

(keeping this one for historical reference)

---

Seems like a specific instance of a more common problem in Terraform: Concatenating variables.

Using locals to concatenate should fix it. See https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html

An example from https://stackoverflow.com/a/61506549/132438:

```
locals {
  BUCKET_NAME = [
    "bh.${var.TENANT_NAME}.o365.attachments",
    "bh.${var.TENANT_NAME}.o365.eml"
  ]
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
  bucket = "${element(local.BUCKET_NAME, 2)}"
  acl    = "private"
}
```

Comment: I do not think this answered my question. Should I specify 1 for dev and 2 for stg in `"${element(local.BUCKET_NAME, 2)}"` ?

Comment: Oh, forget about the array. The important part is that the concatenation was done inside `locals`, and then just used in `resource`.

Comment: Function calls not allowed

  on provider.tf line 9, in terraform:
   9:     bucket         = element(local.BUCKET_NAME, 1)

Functions may not be called here.