# How to create a storage account for a remote state dynamically?

Tags: azure, terraform

I know inorder to have a remote state in my terraform code, i must create a storage account,and a container. Usually, it is done manually, but i am trying to create the storage account and the container dynamically using the below code:

```
    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "state_resource_group" {
      name     = "RG-Terraform-on-Azure"
      location = "West Europe"
    }
    
    
    terraform {
    
      backend "azurerm" {
        resource_group_name  = "RG-Terraform-on-Azure"
        storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.state_storage_account.name
        container_name       = azurerm_storage_container.state_container.name
        key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
      }
    
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_storage_account" "state_storage_account" {
      name                     = random_string.storage_account_name.result
      resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.state_resource_group.name
      location                 = azurerm_resource_group.state_resource_group.location
      account_tier             = "Standard"
      account_replication_type = "LRS"
    
      tags = {
        environment = "staging"
      }
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_storage_container" "state_container" {
      name                  = "vhds"
      storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.state_storage_account.name
      container_access_type = "private"
    }
    
    
    resource "random_string" "storage_account_name" {

      length  = 14
      lower   = true
      numeric = false
      upper   = false
      special = false
  }
```

But, the above code complains that:

```
│ Error: Variables not allowed
│
│   on main.tf line 11, in terraform:
│   11:     storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.state_storage_account.name
│
│ Variables may not be used here.
```

So,I already know that the i cannot use variables in the backend `block`, however i am wondering if there is a solution which enable me to create the storage account and the container dynamically and store the state file in there ?

Point:
i have already seen [this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65838989/variables-may-not-be-used-here-during-terraform-init) but the `.conf` file did not work for me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can't be done in the same Terraform file. The backend has to exist before anything else. Terraform requires the backend to exist when you run `terraform init`. The backend is accessed to read the state as the very first step Terraform performs when you do a `plan` or `apply`, before any resources are actually created.

In the past I've automated the creation of the storage backend using a CLI tool. If you wanted to automate it with terraform it would have to be in a separate Terraform workspace, but then where would the backend for *that* workspace be?

In general, it doesn't really work to create the backend in Terraform.

Comment: I have been looking for the same and your answer would saved me lot of time