# Enter Azure storage account variably in Terraform main.tf

Tags: azure, terraform, github-actions, infrastructure-as-code

How do I pass the Terraform storage account for the backend as variable?
I get the following  error:

```
#main.tf

terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.3"
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "rg-tfstate"
    storage_account_name = var.arg5_terraformStorageAccount
    container_name       = "tfstate"
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
    
  }
```

```
#variables.tf

variable "arg5_terraformStorageAccount" {
  type        = string
  description = "terraformStorageAccount (sensitive)"
  sensitive   = true
}
```

```
│ Error: Variables not allowed
│ 
│   on main.tf line 7, in terraform:
│    7:     storage_account_name = var.arg5_terraformStorageAccount
│ 
│ Variables may not be used here.
```

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65838989/variables-may-not-be-used-here-during-terraform-init?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, as you can't use any variables in `backend`. You have to hardcode the value, or develop some-kind of wrapper around TF to do simple find-and-search substitution.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using substitution.
So I renamed my main.tf file to main.tftemplate
In there I named the variable that I wanted to define dynamically `STORAGEACCOUNT`
In my Github Actions I specified a variable called `AZURE_TF_STORAGE_ACCOUNT`

Then before I run Terraform Apply, I run the following 
`sed "s/STORAGEACCOUNT/${{  vars.AZURE_TF_STORAGE_ACCOUNT  }}/g" main.tftemplate > main.tf`
This replaces `STORAGEACCOUNT` in main.tftemplate with the variable I added to Github Actions and it writes it into the main.tf file.

You can do that with any String inside a file.