# (terraform) Variables not allowed: Variables may not be used here

Tags: terraform, environment-variables, devops, terraform-provider-aws, cicd

I am creating some resources via Terraform that look like this:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "xx" {
  family                   = "xx"
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE", "EC2"]
  container_definitions    = <<TASK_DEFINITION
  [
  {
    "name": "primary",
    "image": "xx",
    "environment": [
      {"PORT": "80", "CONTAINER_CONFIG": var.CONTAINER_CONFIG}}
    ],
  }
]
TASK_DEFINITION
}
```

I do not want to push the hardocded value of a variable (eg CONTAINER_CONFIG) to Github. I don't run terraform apply locally. Terraform is only applied when code is pushed and Github actions run.

How can I use enviornment variables to ensure that the github actions can use the actual variable value without actually pushing the value?

I already created a Github secret and added it to my to Github action .yml file like this:

```
 - name: Terraform apply
        if: steps.plan.outputs.exitcode == 2
        run: terraform apply tfplan
        env:
          TF_VAR_CONTAINER_CONFIG: ${{ secrets.GTM_CONTAINER_CONFIG }}
```

and put this in my vars.tf file:

```
variable "CONTAINER_CONFIG" {
  type      = string
  default   = var.TF_VAR_CONTAINER_CONFIG
  sensitive = true
}
```

With this setup, I get this error on terraform init:

```
Error: Variables not allowed
│ 
│ On variables.tf line 3: Variables may not be used here.
```

If I remove the following part

```
default   = var.TF_VAR_CONTAINER_CONFIG
```

I would still get this error:

```
Error: ECS Task Definition container_definitions is invalid: Error decoding JSON: invalid character 'v' looking for beginning of value
│ 
│   with aws_ecs_task_definition.xx,
│   on gtm.tf line 53, in resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "xx":
│   53:   container_definitions    = <<TASK_DEFINITION
│   54:   [
│   55:   {
│   56:     "name": "preview",
│   57:     "image": "gcr.io/xxx",
│   58:     "environment": [
│   59:       {"PORT": "80", "CONTAINER_CONFIG": var.CONTAINER_CONFIG}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment variable `TF_VAR_CONTAINER_CONGIF` [will automatically be picked up by Terraform](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/environment-variables#tf_var_name), and used to fill the value of the `CONTAINER_CONFIG` variable defined in your Terraform code.

The syntax you are trying to use here is incorrect:

```
variable "CONTAINER_CONFIG" {
  type      = string
  default   = var.TF_VAR_CONTAINER_CONFIG
  sensitive = true
}
```

The syntax is trying to tell Terraform to use another variable as the default value for this variable. That's invalid because you can't have variables reference other variables. What you are actually trying to do is tell Terraform to pull in an Environment variable here, but this isn't the correct syntax for that either.

Just delete the entire `default   = var.TF_VAR_CONTAINER_CONFIG` line, and you will get past this error.

Comment: as mentioned above in the qs, even if i remove that line, i still get this error: ```Error: ECS Task Definition container_definitions is invalid: Error decoding JSON: invalid character 'v' looking for beginning of value```

Comment: Yes but that is an entirely different error that gets you past the syntax issue you are currently facing because of your invalid variable declaration. Without seeing the actual contents of the `TF_VAR_CONTAINER_CONFIG` environment variable there isn't much we can do to help you with that issue. Perhaps you need to wrap it in quotes or something. I would start by logging the value of that variable to make sure it is set correctly to the value you think it is.

Comment: Ok so the value inside my github secret looks like this:

```aW2345678w==```

ending with question marks. I tried putting the string into quotation marks as well but it's still the same error

Comment: I see the issue now, you are trying to reference the value inside a HEREDOC. You need to replace `var.CONTAINER_CONFIG` with `"${var.CONTAINER_CONFIG}"` inside the container definition.